# Why does my multiprocess queue not appear to be thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, message-queue, python-multiprocessing

I am building a watchdog timer that runs another Python program, and if it fails to find a check-in from any of the threads, shuts down the whole program. This is so it will, eventually, be able to take control of needed communication ports. The code for the timer is as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
from copy import deepcopy

PATH_TO_FILE = r'.\test_program.py'
WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT = 2

class Watchdog:

    def __init__(self, filepath, timeout):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.threadIdQ = Queue()
        self.knownThreads = {}

    def start(self):
        threadIdQ = self.threadIdQ

        process = Process(target = self._executeFile)
        process.start()
        try:
            while True:
                unaccountedThreads = deepcopy(self.knownThreads)

                # Empty queue since last wake. Add new thread IDs to knownThreads, and account for all known thread IDs
                # in queue
                while not threadIdQ.empty():
                    threadId = threadIdQ.get()
                    if threadId in self.knownThreads:
                        unaccountedThreads.pop(threadId, None)
                    else:
                        print('New threadId < {} > discovered'.format(threadId))
                        self.knownThreads[threadId] = False

                # If there is a known thread that is unaccounted for, then it has either hung or crashed.
                # Shut everything down.
                if len(unaccountedThreads) > 0:
                    print('The following threads are unaccounted for:\n')
                    for threadId in unaccountedThreads:
                        print(threadId)
                    print('\nShutting down!!!')
                    break
                else:
                    print('No unaccounted threads...')

                sleep(self.timeout)

        # Account for any exceptions thrown in the watchdog timer itself
        except:
            process.terminate()
            raise

        process.terminate()


    def _executeFile(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'r') as f:
            exec(f.read(), {'wdQueue' : self.threadIdQ})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wd = Watchdog(PATH_TO_FILE, WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT)
    wd.start()
```

I also have a small program to test the watchdog functionality

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from queue import SimpleQueue

Q_TO_Q_DELAY = 0.013

class QToQ:

    def __init__(self, processQueue, threadQueue):
        self.processQueue = processQueue
        self.threadQueue = threadQueue
        Thread(name='queueToQueue', target=self._run).start()

    def _run(self):
        pQ = self.processQueue
        tQ = self.threadQueue
        while True:
            while not tQ.empty():
                sleep(Q_TO_Q_DELAY)
                pQ.put(tQ.get())

def fastThread(q):
    while True:
        print('Fast thread, checking in!')
        q.put('fastID')
        sleep(0.5)

def slowThread(q):
    while True:
        print('Slow thread, checking in...')
        q.put('slowID')
        sleep(1.5)

def hangThread(q):
    print('Hanging thread, checked in')
    q.put('hangID')
    while True:
        pass

print('Hello! I am a program that spawns threads!\n\n')

threadQ = SimpleQueue()

Thread(name='fastThread', target=fastThread, args=(threadQ,)).start()
Thread(name='slowThread', target=slowThread, args=(threadQ,)).start()
Thread(name='hangThread', target=hangThread, args=(threadQ,)).start()

QToQ(wdQueue, threadQ)
```

As you can see, I need to have the threads put into a queue.Queue, while a separate object slowly feeds the output of the queue.Queue into the multiprocessing queue. If instead I have the threads put directly into the multiprocessing queue, or do not have the QToQ object sleep in between puts, the multiprocessing queue will lock up, and will appear to always be empty on the watchdog side.

Now, as the multiprocessing queue is supposed to be thread and process safe, I can only assume I have messed something up in the implementation. My solution seems to work, but also feels hacky enough that I feel I should fix it.

I am using Python 3.7.2, if it matters.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 (`from queue import Queue`) and I can't get this to fail. I can send ids directly thru' `wdQueue` or via a `Queue` using `QToQ` and Watchdog always picks up `hangID` and shuts down the program.

Comment: **Update** although without the `hangThread` it always shuts down at some point.

Comment: Your `except` wants to be a `finally`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `test_program.py` exits.

I changed the last few lines to this:

```
tq = threadQ
# tq = wdQueue    # option to send messages direct to WD

t1 = Thread(name='fastThread', target=fastThread, args=(tq,))
t2 = Thread(name='slowThread', target=slowThread, args=(tq,))
t3 = Thread(name='hangThread', target=hangThread, args=(tq,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
QToQ(wdQueue, threadQ)

print('Joining with threads...')
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()

print('test_program exit')
```

The calls to `join()` means that the test program never exits all by itself since none of the threads ever exit.

So, as is, `t3` hangs and the watchdog program detects this and detects the unaccounted for thread and stops the test program.

If `t3` is removed from the above program, then the other two threads are well behaved and the watchdog program allows the test program to continue indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you! Joining the threads does seem to fix the issue, even when I don't create QToQ, and the threads write directly to the multiprocessing queue instead. I'm still confused as to why using QToQ seemed to solve the problem, but I will investigate that later; this is clearly a better solution.

Comment: Interesting side note: I tried putting a check of process.is_alive() in the watchdog timer loop, but it always returned true, even when the bug was happening. However, it does still seem like the problem was process exiting, as something as simple as a while True: pass also seemed to fix it.

Comment: You should try not to have a busy wait, eg `while True:pass`, but instead have a reasonable block like: `t1.join()`. This reduces the cpu load on your server.